# How to do this GROUP BY query in Django's ORM with annotate and aggregate

Tags: python, django, orm, group-by

I don't really have groked how to translate `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to Django's `QuerySet.annotate` and `QuerySet.aggregate`. I'm trying to translate this SQL query into ORM speak

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM pub_date) as year, EXTRACT(month from pub_date) as month, COUNT(*) as article_count FROM articles_article GROUP BY year,month;
```

which outputs this:

```
[(2008.0, 10.0, 1L), # year, month, number of articles
(2009.0, 2.0, 1L),
(2009.0, 7.0, 1L),
(2008.0, 5.0, 3L),
(2008.0, 9.0, 1L),
(2008.0, 7.0, 1L),
(2009.0, 5.0, 1L),
(2008.0, 8.0, 1L),
(2009.0, 12.0, 2L),
(2009.0, 3.0, 1L),
(2007.0, 12.0, 1L),
(2008.0, 6.0, 1L),
(2009.0, 4.0, 2L),
(2008.0, 3.0, 1L)]
```

My Django model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_("title"))
    # ... more 
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('publishing date'))
```

This project should run on a couple of different DB systems, so I'm trying to stay away from pure SQL as much as possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think to do it in one query you might have to have month and year as separate fields...

```
Article.objects.values('pub_date').annotate(article_count=Count('title'))
```

That would `group by` by pub_date. But there is no way I can think of to do the equivalent of the `extract` function clause inline there.

If your model were:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_("title"))
    # ... more 
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('publishing date'))
    pub_year = models.IntegerField()
    pub_month = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you could do:

```
Article.objects.values('pub_year', 'pub_month').annotate(article_count=Count('title'))
```

If you are going to do this, I would recommend having `pub_year` and `pub_month` be automatically populated by overriding the `save()` method for Article and extracting the values from `pub_date`.

---

**Edit:**

One way to do it is to use [extra](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none); but it won't grant you database independence...

```
models.Issue.objects.extra(select={'year': "EXTRACT(year FROM pub_date)", 'month': "EXTRACT(month from pub_date)"}).values('year', 'month').annotate(Count('title'))
```

While this will work, I think (untested), it will require you to modify the `extra` fields if you ever change database servers. For instance, in SQL Server you would do `year(pub_date)` instead of `extract(year from pub_date)`...

This might not be so bad if you come up with a custom model manager that you prominently tag as requiring such database engine dependent changes.

Comment: Nice trick, thanks! I need this query only for a single page, which makes it a little hard to justify two extra fields. But using `extra` will do the job for now :)

Comment: The `extra` example that you posted works great. I wish I could upvote this answer more!

Answer (score 2):

You can make an extract with dates: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates-field-kind-order-asc