# Calculate the total value of the Widgets sold each month for a particular year

Tags: python, django

If I have a Django Model that defines a Widget like this:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
    sold = models.DateTimeField()
    price = models.DecimalField()
    .
    .
```

How would I go about getting the total value of the Widgets sold per month for a particular year?

I'd like to end up with a list of 12 monthly totals, for example:

```
[1225, 197, 131, 125, ...
```

This would indicate the total value of the Widgets sold in January was $1225, February $197 etc.

I expect this can be done with a Django Query, but not quite sure how.

**UPDATE**

I'd prefer not to use anything database specific to make changing databases easier. I don't mind if it's not all done in a single query. Doing a query, then some manipulation using Python after is fine.

**UPDATE**

I think I can slightly change some code from an answer to another question I raised to get this:

```
queryset = Widget.objects.filter(sold__year=year)
totals = [0] * 12
for widget in queryset:
    totals[widget.sold.month - 1] += widget.price
return totals
```

Please let me know if I've missed something or if there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908741/how-to-do-this-group-by-query-in-djangos-orm-with-annotate-and-aggregate/1909277#1909277) you could do.

```
Widget.objects.extra(select={'year': "EXTRACT(year FROM sold)", 'month': "EXTRACT(month from sold)"}).values('year', 'month').annotate(Sum('price'))
```

would give you something like

```
[{'price__sum': 1111, 'year': 2010L, 'month': 6L}...]
```

**Edit - without using EXTRACT**

probably not very efficient but...

```
for date in Widget.objects.all().dates('sold','month'):
    values["%s_%s" % (date.year,date.month)] = Widget.objects.filter(sold__month=date.month,sold__year=date.year).aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

Comment: Is this database specific? I'd prefer not to use anything database specific to make changing databases easier. I don't mind if it's not all done in a single query. Doing a query, then some manipulation using Python after if fine.

Comment: @gerty - apologies, yes it's database specific.

Comment: no problem. I should have made that requirement clear when I first asked the question. I've added an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach, but probably not very efficient either

```
month_totals = []
for month in range(1, 13):
    month_total = Widget.objects. \
               filter(sold__gte=datetime.date(the_year, month, 1),
                      sold__lte=datetime.date(the_year, month, 31)). \
               aggregate(month_total=Sum('price')).month_total
    month_totals.append(month_total)
```